# Add anchor point to shape with C#

Tags: c#, anchor, ellipse

I get width and height of a shape (for example an ellipse) from text boxes and draw it.Now I want to add anchor points to stroke of the shape when the user clicks on it so the user can manipulate the shape, something like Adobe Illustrator Ellipse tool and Add Anchor Point Tool. Any idea how to do that?